# How do i call a command on a function without automatically opening on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I'm trying to add a function to each button but when i do, the function opens immediately without me pressing the button in the menu.

Hello, i'm new to programming and i'm trying to learn some basic about creating a menu for a notepad, so far i learned how to create the menu and the buttons inside of it, I'm trying to add a function to each button but when i do, the function opens immediately without me pressing the button in the menu, the only thing that have worked so far is to try the lambda function, but i want to be able to write the function without having to write the whole code for the function after the lambda function.

```
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import*


#Root main window
root = Tk(className=" Text Editor")
textarea = ScrolledText(root, width=80, height=100)
textarea.pack()

# Menu options
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filename = Menu(menu)
edicion = Menu(menu)


# Funciones

def open_file ():
    file = filedialog.askopenfiles(parent=root, mode='rb', title="Select a file")
    if file != None:
        contenidos = file.read()
        textarea.insert('1.0', contenidos)
        file.close

menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filename)
filename.add_command(label="New")
filename.add_command(label="Open", command= open_file)

filename.add_command(label="Save")
filename.add_separator()
filename.add_command(label="Exit")
menu.add_cascade(label="Editar", menu=edicion)
edicion.add_command(label="Cortar")
edicion.add_command(label="Pegar")
edicion.add_command(label="Copiar")
textarea.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
filename.add_command(label="Open", command= open_file())
```

you do not want the extra `()` after your command, that will call your function.  Try without:

```
filename.add_command(label="Open", command= open_file)
```

Comment: I fixed that but it didn't work.